# Flutter - interactive ListTile in ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, flutter

I have a problem with my ListView, essentially what I would like to do is an interactable ListTile. I would like the user to click on the tile and via navigator move them to another page.

Something like this works with buttons (onPressed) but doesn't work with ListTiles:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HomePage.tag);
```

I've tried using OnTap but I can't figure out a way of using that.

```
final list = ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
      title: Text('Barrack Obama'),
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
      title: Text('Neil Armstrong'),
      onTap: ,
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
      title: Text('Ivan Ivanovich Ivanov'),
    ),

  ],
);
```

The list itself is very simple and a test, I'm trying to redirect users when they click on the tile via navigator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
  ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
      title: Text('Neil Armstrong'),
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("your_route_name");
      } ,
    ),
```

Comment: I'm getting an error =    Could not find a generator for route "chat-page" in the _WidgetsAppState.
Even though I have a class created with a String tag

Comment: did you defined your routes in MaterialApp ? otherwise check my updated answer

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, I've a feeling I might have missed something, although I do not know what. My other navigators seem to be working fine, I'm using tags to navigate to them, This one however still cannot find the generator for route.

Comment: Is it using the same materialapp?

Comment: I've managed to fix it, I forgot to add the tag to my main.dart. Thank you for the help,